# How can a decorator change the parameter of the target function before it being called?

Tags: python

How can I modify the parameter of a function about to be called?

I have the function:

```
def display_prev_days(num_days, func):
    for i in range(0,num_days):
        func

def display_date(date,subtract):
    print(date - timedelta(subtract))
```

Basically, I want to run this:

```
display_prev_days(10,display_date(today, ??? ))
```

which will display the previous date with `today - timedelta(i)`

Comment: `display_prev_days(10, lambda sub: display_date(today, sub))` or `from functools import partial; display_prev_days(10, partial(display_date, today))` — And `func(i)` inside that loop.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What function are you trying to decorate?

Comment: @alexx0186 it seems that I always got too late... if you want we can discuss it in the chat